# SQL Function not returning the same as normal query

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

I am using `SQL Server 2008R2` and I have the following scripts.

```
select * from orderSummaryTotal(@orderid,@sessionid)

select
    count(*) as Quantity,
    IsNull(Sum(VatAmount),0) As VATAmount,
    IsNull(Sum(NetAmount),0) As NetAmount,
    IsNull(Sum(GrossAmount),0) as GrossAmount
from tbOrderProduct
where
     Orderid = @orderid
 and sessionid = @sessionid
```

When I run the Second Query it returns me values. Namely a Quantity of 3

However when I run the first Query it returns me a Quantity of 0.

The First Query is a Table Valued Function Here is the code.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[OrderSummaryTotal](@orderid varchar, @sessionid uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS TABLE as
RETURN
  select
      count(*) as Quantity,
      IsNull(Sum(VatAmount),0) As VATAmount,
      IsNull(Sum(NetAmount),0) As NetAmount,
      IsNull(Sum(GrossAmount),0) as GrossAmount
  from tbOrderProduct
  where
       Orderid = @orderid
   and sessionid = @sessionid
```

Both queries are identical but how come one returns a count of 3 and the other does not?  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you qualify the name of `tbOrderProduct` to be `Database.Schema.tbOrderProduct` in both places?  Do you still get a different answer?

Comment: How you can use table-valued function without schema qualifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you have `varchar` in your function definition with no length.

Try changing it to something like `varchar(8000)`, or a number large enough to suit your needs.

Comment: Or preferably to *exactly the same type and length* as the `Orderid` column. :)